# Простой вопрос по IF

Tags: javascript, if

Как сделать две проверки в одном *IF*?

Т.е., к примеру, если на странице есть кнопка, и значение поля 1 равно 100.
Для примера написал скрипт, но он не работает...

```
if (usluga != undefined) && (url.indexOf('https://and123') +1) {
    alert("b")
}
else if (n)
{
    alert("a");
}
```

П.С. по отдельности все работает правильно.

Comment: оберните еще раз условие в скобки

Comment: За что плюс? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy: не понятно. Я не пойму, зачем там `+1` в коде прописано :)

Comment: @Visman, чтобы `-1` превратился в `0` - это такое хитрозаписанное сравнение `... !== -1`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: хм, впервые встречаю.

Comment: @Visman, честно говоря, я тоже впервые. Но вроде должно работать :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: возможно, только, если обернуто скобками будет `(url.indexOf('https://and123') +1)`.

Comment: @Visman, здесь не паскаль и с приоритетами операторов всё хорошо. `1 && 2 + 3` - получится 5.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а так `2 + 3 && 1` -> `1` :)

Comment: @Visman, да, так :)

Comment: @Visman, [приоритеты операций](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), а последнее так, потому что в условии `a && b`, если `a` это true, то возвращается `b`, какой бы он ни был

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я может не правильно понял вопрос, но вот так все работает правильно:

```js
    //Пример данных:
    var usluga;
    var url = ["https://and123", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    var n = true;

    if ((typeof usluga !== undefined) && (url.indexOf('https://and123') +1)) {
        alert("b");
    }
    else if (n)
    {
        alert("a");
    }
```

Comment: Скобки лишние. Две пары. А вопрос был про синтаксическую ошибку из-за отсутствия внешних.

Comment: Только url у него скорее всего строка, а не массив.

Comment: Возможно, я указал, лишь примерные данные, чтоб код отработал.

Comment: Спасибо больше, все работает. Я просто не знал, как правильно поставить скобки.

Answer (score 2):

Удалить

```
-----------------------v----v
if (usluga != undefined) && (url.indexOf('https://and123') +1) {
```